# Reducers: Action-Oriented Reducers or Structure-Oriented Reducers?

Tags: redux, react-redux

**Is it more reasonable to align the reducers to the actions they handle or to the portion of the store that they update?**

Most of the documentation that I've read favors orienting around the structure of the store, but there are a couple concerns that make me think otherwise.

For background, the application I'm structuring is non-trivial and backed by a SQL database (as opposed to NoSQL) which has had implications on how we can reasonably structure data coming from the back-end.  It will have to handle half a dozen different non-trivial use cases such as polling, event reservations and management, lotteries, and so on.

The structure of the store that I was envisioning before reading about aligning reducers with the store structure was:

```
{
    "usersByID": {
        "aef1345ecb986": {
            "eventIDs": [
                "1256",
                "1876",
                "0010"
            ]
        }
        // obviously lots more users
    },
    "eventsByID": {
        "1256": {//stuff},
        "1876": {//stuff},
        "0010": {//stuff}
        // lots more events too
    }
}
```

However, using store-aligned reducers that would mean the root reducer function would look something like:

```
function rootReducer(state, action) {
    return ({
        usersByID: usersReducer(state.usersByID, action),
        eventsByID: eventsReducer(state.eventsByID, action)
    });
}
```

While using action-aligned reducers and segregating them by general category stored in `action.class` would look something like:

```
function rootReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.class) {
        case POLLING:
            return pollingReducer(state, action)
        case EVENTs:
            return eventsReducer(state, action)
        default:
            return defaultReducer(state, action)
    }
}
```

Admittedly, it does mean that every reducer has to be able to act on the full state at once, but what it avoids is the complicating the web of state transitions that could happen on a complex action.  In the federated model, every action has a reducer contains all of the logic to make an atomic update to the store in a neat and orderly fashion.

Please advise on whether I'm thinking of this all correctly or if there is something I'm missing about the seemingly mainstream way of structuring Redux reducers?